# cURL doesn't like the subject and host name mismatch in the ssl cert

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

I'm trying to teach myself the workings of SSL. I need to connect two servers via rest and https over cURL. I got the crt and key selfsigned ok, the browser asks the usual are you sure.. printing the globals shows the ssl apache engine is working... but curl is not.. here is the code (I am playing around with trying to cURL from a virtual box on debian to a debian dev server):

```
$url = 'https://local.domain.net/curl.php';

        // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        // Set a referer
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.internal-server.co.uk");

        // User agent
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/1.0");

        // Timeout in seconds
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

        //don't verify the signiture
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );

        // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        //set the basic auth to any then set the creds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        $username = self::$http_username;
        $password = self::$http_password;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

        $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code

        // Download the given URL, and return output
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
        curl_close($ch);

        print_r($output);

        echo '


';
```

When i run the above php on command line i get the following:

```
0* About to connect() to local.domain.net port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.1.110...
* connected
* Connected to local.domain.net (192.168.1.110) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=internal-server
*        start date: 2014-11-09 21:40:16 GMT
*        expire date: 2024-11-06 21:40:16 GMT
*** SSL: certificate subject name 'internal-server' does not match target host name 'local.domain.net'**
* Closing connection #0
```

The ssl cert and key was created on the dev server via:

```
 openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout apache.key -out apache.crt
```

It created the certificate and key fine, when i connect via a browser there is the usual, 'are you sure'... but for some reason cURL via php wont play ball..

Is it possible to set the subject of a cert manually with openSSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> certificate subject name 'internal-server' does not match target host name 'local.domain.net'

SSL certificate is bound to a specific domain. During creating the certificate by OpenSSL, it should have asked you to input the domain name (`local.domain.net`).

Browser shows you the warning not only because you used self-signed certificate, but also because it doesn't match the domain. This warning can have a lot of different reasons.